# Firebase Storage's OnSuccessListener callback not calling

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-storage

When uploading files through Firebase Storage, the onSuccess method isn't calling.

I'm currently running Android Studio 3.0 Canary 2, with 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.2.6'.

```
fun uploadImage(pathToImage: String, downloadCallback: FirebaseCallback<String?>) {
        val file = Uri.fromFile(File(pathToImage))
        val ref = mStorRef.child("images/"+file.lastPathSegment)

        ref.putFile(file).addOnSuccessListener {
            object : OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> {
                override fun onSuccess(taskSnapshot: UploadTask.TaskSnapshot?) {
                    val url = taskSnapshot?.downloadUrl
                    Log.d("FirebaseManager", "Upload Successful")
                    downloadCallback.callback(url.toString())
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using `{}`, you're passing in a lambda as the listener via [SAM conversion](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions). Inside this lambda, you're defining what should happen on success: you're creating an `object` that's never used. To pass in the `object` as the listener, use `()`:

```
ref.putFile(file).addOnSuccessListener (
    object : OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> {
        override fun onSuccess(taskSnapshot: UploadTask.TaskSnapshot?) {
            val url = taskSnapshot?.downloadUrl
            Log.d("FirebaseManager", "Upload Successful")
            downloadCallback.callback(url.toString())
        }
    }
)
```

Or go with just SAM conversion, without creating an `object` explicitly:

```
ref.putFile(file).addOnSuccessListener { taskSnapshot ->
    val url = taskSnapshot?.downloadUrl
    Log.d("FirebaseManager", "Upload Successful")
    downloadCallback.callback(url.toString())
}
```